# How to store model in `.pb` file with Estimator in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained my model with estimator of TensorFlow. It seems that `export_savedmodel` should be used to make `.pb` file, but I don't really know how to construct the `serving_input_receiver_fn`. Anybody any ideas?
Example code is welcomed.

Extra questions:

1. Is `.pb` the only file I need when I want to reload the model? `Variable` unnecessary?
2. How much will `.pb` reduced the model file size compared with `.ckpt` with adam optimizer?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`freeze_graph.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) to produce a `.pb` from `.ckpt` + `.pbtxt`
if you're using [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), then you'll find these two files in the [`model_dir`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig#model_dir)

```
python freeze_graph.py \
    --input_graph=graph.pbtxt \
    --input_checkpoint=model.ckpt-308 \
    --output_graph=output_graph.pb
    --output_node_names=<output_node>
```

> 1. Is .pb the only file I need when I want to reload the model? Variable unnecessary?

**Yes**, You'll have to know you're model's input nodes and output node names too. Then use [`import_graph_def`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def) to load the .pb file and get the input and output operations using [`get_operation_by_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operation_by_name)

> 2. How much will .pb reduced the model file size compared with .ckpt with adam optimizer?

A .pb file is not a compressed .ckpt file, so there is no "compression rate".

However, there is a way [to optimize your .pb file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py) for inference, and this optimization may reduce the file size as it removes parts of the graph that are training only operations (see the complete description [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py#L16-L49)).

> [comment] how can I get the input and output node names?

You can set the input and output node names using the op `name` parameter.

To list the node names in your `.pbtxt` file, use the following script.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format

with open('graph.pbtxt') as f:
    graph_def = text_format.Parse(f.read(), tf.GraphDef())

print [n.name for n in graph_def.node]
```

> [comment] I found that there is a tf.estimator.Estimator.export_savedmodel(), is that the function to store model in .pb directly? And I'm struggling in it's parameter serving_input_receiver_fn. Any ideas?

`export_savedmodel()` generates a `SavedModel` which is a *universal serialization format for TensorFlow models.* It should contain everything's needed to fit with [TensorFlow Serving APIs](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/apis/prediction_service.proto)

`serving_input_receiver_fn()` is a part of those needed things you have to provide in order to generate a `SavedModel`, it determines the input signature of your model by adding placeholders to the graph.

From the doc

> This function has the following purposes:
>
> - To add placeholders to the graph that the serving system will feed
>     with inference requests.
> - To add any additional ops needed to convert
>     data from the input format into the feature Tensors expected by the
>     model.

If you're receiving your inference requests in the form of serialized `tf.Examples` (which is a typical pattern) then you can use the example provided in the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#preparing_serving_inputs).

```
feature_spec = {'foo': tf.FixedLenFeature(...),
                'bar': tf.VarLenFeature(...)}

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  """An input receiver that expects a serialized tf.Example."""
  serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,
                                         shape=[default_batch_size],
                                         name='input_example_tensor')
  receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}
  features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
```

> [comment] Any idea to list the node names in '.pb'?

It depends on how it was generated.

if it's a [`SavedModel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/saved_model.proto) the use:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    meta_graph_def = tf.saved_model.loader.load(
        sess,
        [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        './saved_models/1519232535')
    print [n.name for n in meta_graph_def.graph_def.node]
```

if it's a [`MetaGraph`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.proto) then use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

with tf.Session() as sess:
    with gfile.FastGFile('model.pb', 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        sess.graph.as_default()
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        print [n.name for n in graph_def.node]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to know that how can I get the input and output nodes names? from the `graph.pbtxt`?

Comment: I found that there is a `tf.estimator.Estimator.export_savedmodel()`, is that the function to store model in `.pb` directly? And I'm struggling in it's parameter `serving_input_receiver_fn`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use a node in `.pbtxt` as input node to optimize `.pb`, however the node in `.pbtxt` is not in `.pb` as the debug infomation. Any idea to list the node names in '.pb'?

Comment: For the "node" session, "MetaGraph" part: how can you have a 'model.pb' file before you run freeze_graph.py?

Comment: @kennyut when exporting the modèle with [`tf.estimator.Estimator.export_savedmodel()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#export_savedmodel)

Comment: how can i load my AlexNet.pb file then use it for classification ?